# Ocunit - Creating singleton test class to share code among classes

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, singleton, ocunit

I just started to write unit test case for my code.
While writing I just absorbed that many  test case classes are using some common code and also it need a common variable in among the classes.

So I have decided to create a singleton class to hold all these values. In which this singleton class will be inherited with sentesting.

So Here my question is it possible to create a singleton test class. ?

Note : I have created a singleton but it is not at all working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OCUnit shares the same architecture as the other xUnit frameworks. To run a test case, it

1. Instantiates a test case object. (It's usually called a "test fixture" where the fixture has ivars of other objects useful across several tests.)
2. Calls setUp
3. Runs one specific test method
4. Calls tearDown

For the common variable you want, define it as an ivar. Then initialize it in `-setUp`. If it needs explicit cleanup afterwards, do so in `-tearDown`.

It's very important to avoid sharing objects between tests, because each test should stand have consistent pass/fail behavior on its own. Sharing objects pollutes this, creating potential dependencies between your tests. Since singletons are a common way to share objects, they generally work against unit testing strategy.

For a step-by-step example of unit testing (specifically test-driven development) in Xcode using Objective-C or Swift, see https://qualitycoding.org/tdd-kata/

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying but I have a question like suppose consider am hitting service at the beginning to pull out some urls from the server and I have to use those urls to test my rest of application services. In this case consider I have written it in  different classes. By your answer I have to hit server every time to pull urls and is it i have to hit server agin and again in each classes. ? or else can you suggest me a good way to follow this one,

Comment: @nik It depends on the type of testing you want to do: Do you want to test your client, or your service? For client tests, I stick to true unit tests that don't hit a real service at all. Avoiding real service calls keeps tests fast and consistent. Think about how to alter your design to isolate the service. (TDD avoids such problems by designing your code from the tests backwards, instead of trying to design tests to fit existing code.)

Answer (score 0):

Yep Here i found in this that we **cannot** create a singleton class which inherit sentesting.

We can only create singleton which inherit from NSObject.